# could not draw line on visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opengl, visual-c++, windows-7, graphics2d

I made program graphics drawLine in visual studio 2010. Here are the codes :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<GL/glut.h>

void userdraw(void);

void drawDot(float x, float y)

{

    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    glVertex2f(x,y);
    glEnd();
}

void drawLine(float x1, float y1,float x2,float y2)
{
    glBegin(GL_LINES) ;
        glVertex2f(x1,y1) ;
        glVertex2f(x2,y2) ;
    glEnd() ;
}

void setColor(float red,float green, float blue)
{
    glColor3f(red, green, blue);
}
void userdraw(void)
{ 

    setColor(1.,0.,0.);
    drawLine(50.,40.,110.,40.);
    drawLine(60.,50.,120.,50.);     

    glEnd();
}

void display(void)
{
    //clear screen
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    userdraw();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit( &argc,argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB );
    glutInitWindowSize(640,480);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100,150);
    glutCreateWindow ("my first aplication"); 
    glClearColor(1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0);
    gluOrtho2D(0.,640.,-240.,240.);
    glutIdleFunc(display);
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;

}
```

There are no error when I debugged the program, but the result was just an empty window with no line.
Help me solves this problem

Comment: Is the window white? That will tell you if at least the `glClear()` worked. Other than that, you have an unbalanced `glEnd()` in `userdraw()`. That will be an error, but I wouldn't have expected it to keep anything from rendering.

Comment: Some other computers have no problem with that program. The line shows up.
So what do you suggest?